# dynamic report 2012 ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

**using Report Class for dynamic reprot on

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering namespace
reference  Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore.dll ( Last Version 2012-06)**

The report class contain all reportViewer elements
to relate RDLC or RDL file to the report class i'm  trying  Serialize the class
this option not avilable ...

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
FileStream fs = new FileStream(report_path, FileMode.Open);
ms = new MemoryStream();
fs.Position = 0;
ms.SetLength(fs.Length);
fs.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fs.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
report = (Report)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
```

**
trying to Serialize the class and getting an error
checking bool=typeof(report).is Serializable   >>    false

So maybe there is other solution to work with the Report Class ?

** for dynamic report >>
i'm using ReportDefinition xsd and working with ReportDefinition Class from xsd.exe

Dserialize option working as well to change report definition on run time

the new report class is a replacement of this option  !

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking, can you edit your question and clarify?

Comment: i edit my question i hope you can understand

Comment: Can you specify which.net version you are using? is it 4.0? 4.5?